# Crash on __dispatch_call_block_and_release

Tags: ios, crash, dispatch

I have an iOS app, and I am getting quite amount of this crash.
And it seems that it is not related to my code. Do you have any idea why the app can crash because of this. Is there something that I can do to prevent these crashes.

```
    Thread 9 Crashed:
1    libobjc.A.dylib     _objc_msgSend + 16
2    libdispatch.dylib   __dispatch_call_block_and_release + 13
3    libdispatch.dylib   __dispatch_queue_drain + 239
4    libdispatch.dylib   __dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 41
5    libdispatch.dylib   __dispatch_worker_thread2 + 211
6    libsystem_c.dylib   __pthread_wqthread + 295
```

Comment: It seems a multithreading issue, an issue related with GCD. Are you using any external library or something that is using GCD or aye you yourself using GCD somewhere in your app?

Comment: without code this qn will have no good answer

Comment: Actually that is the problem. Crash report does not say anything where it is happening in my code. I don't know, how can I detect it. I guess I have to check every single dispatch call in the code. In some places I am using, in some cases an external library is using GCD. Especially the sdwebimage library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCD is used in your app. So..
Bring more detail-info please? code where it's occurred?
May be you need copy block vs retain, may be you need use __block vars correctly. May be something else. Obviously, your object had been captured by block is released and deallocated when happens queue_drain, and after that you call method of the object in other scope, or in the block scope.

Comment: Actually that is the problem. Crash report does not say anything where it is happening in my code. I don't know, how can I detect it. I guess I have to check every single dispatch call in the code.

Comment: @hakasaglam the crash is happening calling a block in your code. So don't say you don't know where it's happening. Post your code creating and dispatching the block.